# C++ How to read text from a basic text file and store into two different arrays

Tags: c++

I'm having some issues with my lab for computer science. The goal for this assignment is to read text from a text file that was created from another program that shows as the following all on one line.

```
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR 40000 50000 60000 70000 35000 45000 55000 65000 25000 26000 27000 28000 31000 32000 33000 34000 42000 43000 44000 45000 10000 20000 30000 40000
```

and then assign to two different arrays. One one dimensional array and one two dimensional array. The one dimensional array is a string array with a size of 6 that will hold the names of company's (ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO, and PQR) and the two dimensional array is a int array with 6 rows and 4 columns that will hold the profit each company made in each quarter. So to better show what I mean here is what it would look like in a table.

```
ABC   40000 50000 60000 70000
DEF   35000 45000 55000 65000
GHI   25000 26000 27000 28000
JKL   31000 32000 33000 34000
MNO   42000 43000 44000 45000
PQR   10000 20000 30000 40000
```

Below is the chunks of code from my program that I'm having trouble with. I removed the chunks that are irrelevant to the question such as the displaying of the array and a search index which I know work after testing with initialized arrays. I'm still fairly new to C++ and coding in general so I used some fairly crude methods in an attempt to get this to work. My apologies in advance. Also, I'm not asking for you to do this for me. I'm just wanting some help understanding how to get this to work properly especially the section that is blatantly wrong.

NOTE: The functions need to stay separate for the assignment and there can only be two. So, I can't make it easier and put them into one function.

EDIT: Forgot to add what the code was failing to do. When the program attempts to read the file and assign the data to the respective array's it's having issues. The one dimensional array that holds company names is not getting any info and the two dimensional array that holds the profits are all the same with the value of -9.25596e+061

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


const int COMPANY_AMOUNT = 6, AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS = 4;
void ReadData(int, int, int, string&, int&);

int main()
{
    int x = 0, // current position of the array
        y = 0, // current position of the array
        Array; // Used to differentiate which array is going to be worked on
    string Company[COMPANY_AMOUNT]; // Array for Company names
    string Name1; // Holds the name of the company as a reference variable when sent to the ReadData function.
    int Name2; // Holds the money amount for the company quarter as a reference variable when sent to the ReadData function.
    double CompanySales[COMPANY_AMOUNT][AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS]; // Array for Company profits

    for (x = 0; x < COMPANY_AMOUNT; x++)
    {
        Array = 0; // set to 0 and passed to ReadData to let it know that the Company[] array is being worked on.
        ReadData(x, y, Array, Name1, Name2);
        Name1 = Company[x] ;    
    }
    for (x = 0; x < COMPANY_AMOUNT; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS; y++)
        {
            Array = 1; // set to 1 and passed to ReadData to let it know that CompanySales[][] array is being worked on.
            ReadData(x,y,Array, Name1, Name2);
            Name2 = CompanySales[x][y];
        }    
    }
}

void ReadData(int x, int y, int Array, string& Name1, int& Name2)
{
    // My goal here was to create the array's everytime ReadData is called on and then it would send back whatever was in the [x] or [x][y] spot through the Name1 or Name2 reference variables.
    int value = 0, CompanySales[COMPANY_AMOUNT][AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS], a, b, cash,  number;
    string value1, Company[COMPANY_AMOUNT], name;

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("C:\\TEMP\\Data.txt");

    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        system("Pause");
        exit(PROGRAM_FAILURE)
    }
    else
    {
        while (inputFile >> number) // This is the section where I have trouble. It doesn't read properly and gives me awkward outputs later on.
        {
            for (a = 0; a < COMPANY_AMOUNT; a++)
            {
                inputFile >> name;
                name = Company[a];
            }
            for (a = 0; a < COMPANY_AMOUNT; a++) // Company_Amount = 6
            {
                for (b = 0; b < AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS; b++) // Amount_of_Quarters = 4
                {
                    inputFile >> cash;
                    cash = CompanySales[a][b];
                }
            }

        inputFile.close();

        if (Array == 0)
        {
            Company[x] = Name1;
        }
        else if (Array == 1)
        {
            Company[x][y] = Name2;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Company` and `CompanySales` arrays in `main()` are completely unaffected by the modifications to the local arrays of the same names in `ReadData`. And `inputFile >> name;` followed immediately by `name = Company[a];` makes no sense, as it completely overwrites the datum just-read (stored in `name`, assuming the extraction worked, which is a guess as it is never checked) with the array content (which is indeterminant). The same is true for `inputFile >> cash` later in the code.

Comment: You're just giving us the code and not telling us what the problem is!

Comment: Yeah. Since array's can't be used as references (to my knowledge) I was going to try and get around it by having ReadData create the array's each time it's called on and then pass it's value in [x] or [x][y] position through Name1 or Name2 respectively and then assign those to the array's in the main function. From what I can tell this method works, but it's not reading the file correctly. Instead it's assigning each value in the int array as -9.25596e+061 and not assigning anything for the string array.

Comment: What do you mean by only seeing code? Am I the only one that sees the large amount of text I put beforehand and the comments in the code? If so I'll attempt to fix the formatting or make it more readable.

Comment: @ChipmunkSpanton What I meant by that was that you weren't telling us what you're code was failing to do.

Comment: ah. I addressed it in my previous comment. I'll make sure to move that into the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be for the task you are trying to achieve.  Your `ReadData()` function is trying to do too much, which is complicating the rest of your code.  Get rid of it, then you can simplify the code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

const int COMPANY_AMOUNT = 6, AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS = 4;

int main()
{
    std::string Company[COMPANY_AMOUNT]; // Array for Company names
    double CompanySales[COMPANY_AMOUNT][AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS]; // Array for Company profits

    std::ifstream inputFile("C:\\TEMP\\Data.txt");
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        system("Pause");
        return PROGRAM_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < COMPANY_AMOUNT; x++)
    {
        inputFile >> std::ws >> Company[x];
        if (!inputFile)
        {
            std::cout << "Error reading file.\n";
            system("Pause");
            return PROGRAM_FAILURE;
        }

        if (inputFile.eof())
        {
            std::cout << "Unexpected EOF while reading file.\n";
            system("Pause");
            return PROGRAM_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < COMPANY_AMOUNT; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS; y++)
        {
            inputFile >> std::ws >> CompanySales[x][y];
            if (!inputFile)
            {
                std::cout << "Error reading file.\n";
                system("Pause");
                return PROGRAM_FAILURE;
            }
        }    
    }

    inputFile.close();

    // use arrays as neded...

    return 0;
}
```

If you absolutely must have a `ReadData()` function, then you need to re-design it, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

const int COMPANY_AMOUNT = 6, AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS = 4;
void ReadData(std::string*, double[COMPANY_AMOUNT][AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS]);

int main()
{
    std::string Company[COMPANY_AMOUNT]; // Array for Company names
    double CompanySales[COMPANY_AMOUNT][AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS]; // Array for Company profits

    ReadData(Company, CompanySales);

    // use arrays as neded...

    return 0;
}

void ReadData(std::string* Names, double Sales[COMPANY_AMOUNT][AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS])
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("C:\\TEMP\\Data.txt");
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        system("Pause");
        exit(PROGRAM_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < COMPANY_AMOUNT; x++)
    {
        inputFile >> std::ws >> Names[x];
        if (!inputFile)
        {
            std::cout << "Error reading file.\n";
            system("Pause");
            exit(PROGRAM_FAILURE);
        }

        if (inputFile.eof())
        {
            std::cout << "Unexpected EOF while reading file.\n";
            system("Pause");
            exit(PROGRAM_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < COMPANY_AMOUNT; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < AMOUNT_OF_QUARTERS; y++)
        {
            inputFile >> std::ws >> Sales[x][y];
            if (!inputFile)
            {
                std::cout << "Error reading file.\n";
                system("Pause");
                exit(PROGRAM_FAILURE);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly I can't do it like this. It has to be two separate functions. The ReadData is the one that opens the file and reads it and then sends the values back to main to be put into the local arrays there.

Comment: Given the way you designed `ReadData()`, having it do everything is a lousy design choice, especially considering that your implementation was full of mistakes. But I have updated my answer to show an additional example. If you can't change the design of the function, then you have major problems with your requirement.

Comment: I would have to agree with your statement about the requirement. Regarding the changes, I went to test it out and it's giving me a compiler error of "error C2664: 'void ReadData(std::string *,double **)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'double [6][4]' to 'double **' "

Comment: oh wait no my apologies. That was my fault. I copied a small section incorrectly.EDIT: oh haha. I went to look at your code again and saw it changed and just thought I misread it earlier then I saw your comment after I made this one. I'll go test it.

Comment: It reads it perfectly now thank you. We just learned about pointers and it makes me happy to see that you can use them to allow the array to pass to a function and return like this. Also, thanks for the tips regarding checking the end of a file. It works a lot better than what the text book has us do if I keep in mind what Remy said below.

Answer (score -1):

Can't leave a comment, but first off, try this:
instead of

```
while (inputFile >> number)
```

try this

```
while (!inputFile.eof)
```

I forget the exact syntax sitting here, I'm a student too, don't check for still reading, just look at either end of file, or peek at the next value to see if it is valid.

Comment: -1 This is very bad advice. `eof()` is not updated until after a read is attempted. If the loop is controlled by `eof()` then no reading will ever take place.  Using `>>` is the preferred approach. It attempts to read and updates the `eof`, `bad`, and `fail` bits as needed, then returns a reference to the stream, which can be converted to a `bool` by `if` to check for a failure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We have yet to talk about it, but it seems easier to use than what I have. The issue is when I tried it it gives me a build error saying there is a "string subscript out of range"

Comment: This is not just very bad advice.  It is utterly hopeless advice.  In fact, the problem with it is a [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-eof.html)! This error used to be called the "Pascal disease", after a language in which testing for EOF was the right thing to do.

Comment: Well, sorry for providing bad advice, as I said, I'm a student, and the way this is how we're were handling file input in our classes.